# Adding Characters to a string in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace

I have a data frame with a few columns, one column is ID and if ID begins with a numeric value I need to add characters to begin else leave alone.

[image]

And my desired out put would need to look like this:

[image]

Comment: only looking at the ID (Fist Column) ignore all other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `grepl` to search for whether the first element of each string is a numeric value. '^' looks at the first value in the string, and '[0-9]' matches digits 0 through 9. If there is a match, the character 'E' is prepended to the front. Otherwise the string is returned unchanged:

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(V1 = c('725901', '759021', 'S00168'))

df$V1 <- sapply(df$V1, function(x) ifelse(grepl("^[0-9]", x), paste0('E', x), x))
```

generates:

```
       V1
1 E725901
2 E759021
3  S00168
```